# perl how to stop external program in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a perl script that executes external program and stop it.

The external program will not stop by itself because I am supposed to hit 'enter' on command shell it is running on.

Is there any way to stop the external program in perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to stop the external program in perl script?

In a word, yes. But the implementation depends on the platform on which you're running your application.

On all the platforms that perl supports, you could use `system()` to call an external program. But then your original program will wait and do nothing until the external program exits, so `system()` doesn't fit your situation.

Since you didn't mention your platform (OS), two main platforms should be talked here:

Unix-like OS: First of all you could `fork` a child process, and in child process, use `exec` to call the external program. Then in parent process, you could wait the child process, and send it `TERM` signals (or other signals which will terminate the process by default) when you would like to stop the external program.

```
if (($pid = fork) == 0) {
    exec("$external_program $arg");
} else {
    # do something...
    kill "TERM", $pid;
}
```

Win32 OS: I would like to mention that on Win32 platform, the child process `fork`ed  is actually a pseudo-process, and Win32 doesn't support the signal methodology like Unix. You could follow the solution in `1` for Win32, but as far as I tried, child process often misses the signals, for example, when child process is sleeping or waiting for a socket connection. **This could be very unstable.**

Instead, [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.14/Process.pm) is a better solution. It use Win32 API to create and manipulate processes.

```
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj, $external_program, $arg, 
                       0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, ".") or die;
# do something ...
$ProcessObj->Kill($exitcode);
```

Basically that's the principle. If you want a cross-platform solution, there's a module [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) on CPAN, which supports both platforms.

```
use Proc::Background;
my $proc = Proc::Background->new($command, $arg);  
# do something ...
$proc->die;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a fork in Perl to get the pid (process id) of the child process. See the last comment [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=671047).

Once you have pid you can use the Unix `kill` ([see this site](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_kill.htm)) command from your Perl script using any of the methods described [here](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481882/need-to-abort-a-perl-script-make-it-die-from-another-script) question also indicates that you could write the pid from inside whatever program you started to a separate file. You could then read in the pid in that file from your calling script.